# Get default selected item on page refresh

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a website build on a MEAN stack where I have a selectbox with some citynames being retreived from MongoDB. Now I use Angular to display these names in my HTML, but now I want a default name to be displayed when the page is loaded so at least some information is shown. I've already searched what I could use, and ng-init was suggested but this did not work for me. Are there any other options?

This is my HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="cityCtrl">
  <div class="container plumbers">
    <div class="searchbox">
       <div class="plumber-by-city col-sm-12" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
       <div class="title-1">Zoek op plaatsnaam</div>
          <select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="item as item.city for item in items"></select><span class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my angular that retrieves data from DB:

```
app.controller('cityCtrl', function($scope,$http){
  $scope.items = [];

  $http.get('/getdata').then(function(d){
    console.log(d);
    $scope.items = d.data;
  },function(err){
    console.log(err);
  });
});
```

Comment: You should init `selectedItem`. try this `$scope.selectedItem =$scope.items[0]`

Comment: Alternatively to Hadi's answer, you could initialise `$scope.items = [ {city: amsterdam} ]` or however your response looks

Comment: What value should be shown as default `selectedItem`?

Comment: Thanx Hadi, this did the trick :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-selected` and `||` operator such that if there is a value for `selectedItem` then it would be selected or else the first object of the array is selected by default.

```js
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []).controller("cityCtrl", function($scope) { 
 $scope.items = [{city: 'abc'}, {city: 'cde'}, {city: 'fgh'}];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="cityCtrl">
  <div class="container plumbers">
    <div class="searchbox">
       <div class="plumber-by-city col-sm-12" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
       <div class="title-1">Zoek op plaatsnaam</div>
          <select ng-selected="selectedItem = selectedItem || items[0]" ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="item as item.city for item in items"></select><span class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
       </div>
       {{selectedItem}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```